# How To Stop Openshift From Creating Log Files

Tags: openshift, logfiles

Openshift creates tons of log files and my gear quota exceeds in one week. I don't want to delete the log file every week. It is showing error logs and access logs. Error logs are very less in size 1-5 MB each, but access logs are 30-60 MB each.

```
How to stop open shift from creating log files?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line argument for cleaning the log files.

`rhc app tidy`

so running this as a cron job daily would partially solve your issue.